# How would I get the string after the "!"

Tags: python

I want to do something of the following,but I am having issues

```
if "!" in line:
    global after-ex == line.after(!)
```

the if "!" in line works fine
but I don't know how to do the actual function.perhaps there may be some import's I do not know of.

Comment: `str = line[line.index("!")+1:]`

Comment: Do this line.split('!')[-1]